# Asking for multiple filenames and seperating them in comma in BATCH

Tags: windows, batch-file

I made a bat that asks the user for a filename and a path. It creates the path first and then moves the file to the path.

```
@echo off

set /p filename="pls enter filename(s): "
set /p filespath="pls enter path: "

mkdir %filespath%
move %filename% %filespath%
```

BUT how can I make it ask for multiple filenames like `blabla.png, test1.png, image.png ...`
and make it seperate each filename by comma and then move the files?

Comment: Iterate over your filenames list using `FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=," %x IN ("%1")` in a subroutine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `goto` command to ask for input multiple times, and append all values to a new variable (`filelist`). E.g.

```sh
@echo off

set filelist=

:start

set filename=
set /p filename="pls enter filename, or Enter when finished: "

if "%filename%"=="" goto :nextstep

set filelist=%filelist% %filename%

goto :start


:nextstep

set filespath=
set /p filespath="pls enter path: "
if "%filespath%"=="" goto :EOF

mkdir %filespath%

for %%f in (%filelist%) do (
    move %%f %filespath%
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to delimiter input like so - you can use a count and index the Variable name to process all input like so:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    For /L %%A IN (1,1,8000) Do (
        Set /P "Filename[%%A]=Drag and Drop or Enter Filename. Type Done to Process }<"
        Set /A Filecount=%%A - 1
        IF /I "!Filename[%%A]!"=="done" (GOTO :Process)
    )

:process
REM Your commands here for filepath and move actions. The below is how to access the indexed variables.
For /L %%B IN (1,1,%Filecount%) DO (ECHO( !Filename[%%B]!)
pause
Exit
```

Answer (score 0):

To save the name of the files in the pseudo array, also check if the folder was created and if the file exists before moving them ...

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d "%~dp0"

:_loop_name_:
set "filename=" && call set /p filename="[ Enter filename's ] if done, just [enter]!! "

echo/!filename!|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe . >nul && (
set /a "_cnt+=1+0" && call set "_filename_!_cnt!=!filename!" && goto :_loop_name_: )

:_loop_path_:
set /p filespath="pls enter path: " || goto :_loop_path_:
echo/!filespath!|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe . >nul || goto :_loop_path_:

if not exist "!filespath!\." mkdir 2>nul "!filespath!" || (echo/ Error MKDir: !filespath! & goto :EOF)
for /l %%L in (1 1 !_cnt!)do if exist "!_filename_%%~L!" (call move /y "!_filename_%%~L!" "!filespath!" >nul 
) else echo/File not found/exist: "!_filename_%%~L!"

%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1
rem./ :: do more task....
endlocal && goto :EOF
```

---